# Cordova App Unable to install 64Bit APK with crosswalk plugin

Tags: android, cordova, webview, cordova-plugins, crosswalk

I have a Cordova Application in which I have installed [crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) plugin. When I build the cordova APP for Android, it creates multiple APKs. I am able to install the armv7. But when I try to install 64Bit APK it gives me some error related to crosswalk.[CrossWalk error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N78zC.png)

When I remove the crosswalk plugin, the 64Bit APK installs fine, but then some of the asset folders (like some folders of images) get missing.

Cordova version : 8.1.2
Cordova Android version : 7.1.4

Do I still need a crosswalk plugin in my Cordova App? Because I read that its deprecated and no more needed.
I will need 64Bit APKs from August as will not be able to upload 32Bit apks on Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to include a web view, as all the modern platforms have native web views.

The Crosswalk plugin is an alternative web view that you can optionally include in your project. It's not required and actually adds to the size of your app, so only include the plugin if you have a specific use case for it.

Removing the Crosswalk plugin should not affect assets like your images, so investigate why that is happening.